# Shouldn't the help-center of this bilingual site be bilingual?

Tags: feature-request, help-center

After having collected a reputation of 16k+, I now tried to read some information on the [help center](https://german.stackexchange.com/help). But I find it really hard to read it, because the **German**-Language-Help-Center is completely written in a foreign language. So my 20th or so try to read this FAQ ended in frustration again.

I find it quite absurd that people (like me) who are German Native Speakers, and want to talk about German language, must learn a foreign language, to be able to understand the rules of this site.

So I suggest to create a German Version of the Help Center, with the same answers and questions as in the existing English version, just translated into German.

Comment: Possibly related, or not: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/468/260760 and http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/65115/260760 and maybe even http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/105169/260760. I would say, don't get your hopes up, the site has far too few users and daily questions to afford localisation. It is somewhat of a vicious circle... until localisation is fully implemented I do not think it is a good idea to create a parallel universe.

Answer (score 2):

The only solution I see to the incompleteness-feeling regarding the missing German translations of the many pages this site has, is to create the German interface. The proposal of this answer is to be able to access that German interface with the following conditions.

1. Asking in English is always allowed.
2. Answering to English questions in English is what is expected.
3. The site does not split, neither do the user's accounts (see *background* below)

---

### Background

I was surprised to notice that the [Russian Language](https://russian.stackexchange.com/) has a sister-site
with a (purely) Russian interface, namely

https://rus.stackexchange.com/

Maybe that's what the solution to your series of questions might be: to create a

*deutsch.stackexchange.com*

(that page does exist, but it redirects to the usual GL.SE) which displays a German interface but which, opposite to that what happened to the Russian site, does transfer your reputation and considers you as owning one account with one reputation, independent on the language you choose to read the interface. **It would be a pity that the reputation might not be transferred, as it happens in the Russian language sites. That would, IMHO, make this site weaker**, instead of prompting its growth.